# iOS Swift 3, Alamorfire: Wait for all image uploading to be finished before calling a function

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift3, alamofire

I have a view which contains multiple buttons which allow users to click and upload image for each button, after upload an image, server will return an URL for that image. A Save button at the bottom of the view which call the api to save all info in the view including urls of these images to my server.

[image]

I'm using Alamofire to upload images.
The problem is that: when user choose an image to upload, I'll call the upload API right away and upload that photo in background, I do not wait until users click Save button and upload all information & images at once.

And I want that when users click on Save button, but the images are not finished uploading, the view will wait for the uploading to be finished then automatically call the Save function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use a [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchgroup).

```
//Create a dispatch group
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for picture in listOfPicturesToUpload {
    //Enter the group
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    self.upload(picture, completion:{
        //Leave the group on upload completion
        dispatchGroup.leave
    })
}

//Called when all the requests are finished
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
    //Call the save function as all the requests are finished.
    self.save()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my question clear, I updated it. The problem is that: when user choose an image to upload, I'll call the upload API right away and upload that photo in background, I do not wait until users click Save button and upload all information & images at once.

Comment: Those are just implementation details, the concept of waiting for multiple requests to finish before doing something still holds.

Comment: oh I forgot that my app supports iOS 9, but the dispatchGroup.notify is available from iOS 10

Comment: You can use the old syntax if you want ( https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452933-dispatch_group_notify).